# Can't input text using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to make a little web scraping app that would gather job listings from dfifrent websites, but I got stuck with filling an input tag.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selections import *


class Pracuj_PL_Extractor():
    def __init__(self, *, key_words = None, location = None, distance = None, specialty = NOT_SPECIFIED, tech = NOT_SPECIFIED, level = NOT_SPECIFIED, Working_Hours = NOT_SPECIFIED, operation_mode = NOT_SPECIFIED):        
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
        
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
        self.driver.get(r'https://pracuj.pl')
        #getting rid of cookie notification
        try:
            cookie_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'size-medium.variant-primary.cookies_b1fqykql'))
                )
            cookie_button.click()
            print("Cookies button detected and clicked!")
        except:
            print("Cookies button not detected")
        
        #changing mode to IT
        it_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-test="tab-item-it"]')
        it_button.click()

        self.input_key_words("")

        self.driver.quit()
        self.driver = None

    def input_key_words(self, key_words):
        key_words_div = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-test="dropdown-element-kw"]')
        input_box = WebDriverWait(key_words_div, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[data-test="input-field"]'))
        )
        input_box.click()
        input_box.send_keys('1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractor = Pracuj_PL_Extractor()
```

Basically, the `input_keywords function` is not working, the input tag seems to get focused tough. It might be an issue with my chrome driver, since I am not able to input any text even when using chrome GUI. I also got some errors regarding ssl, here are my logs:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:20490/devtools/browser/5518bf87-95dc-4478-b02a-934f5d2e1277
Cookies button detected and clicked!
[16536:22760:0930/213802.131:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant HTML would help to better diagnose the problem and construct a definetly-correct answer. However as you've stated that the element seems to be getting focused, I'm assuming the CSS Selector is correct. That being said, as you have defined your `input_keywords method`, there are two issues with it.

- 1. You're passing an `element` as the parameter for the wait. It should take the `driver` as parameter as noted in the [Selenium explicit await docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).
- 2. The `send_keys` method is not taking into account the `key_words` that's being passed by parameter to your function, and is instead sending the literal '1'.

So, assuming the html-related bits are correct, the function body
should read:

```
    def input_key_words(self, key_words):
        input_box = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-test="dropdown-element-kw" > input[data-test="input-field"]')))
        input_box.click()
        input_box.send_keys(key_words)
```

Here you instruct the `driver` to `wait` until the element of tag `input` that has a `data-test` attr with the value `"input-field"`, *[that is a child of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)* the element `div` that has a `data-test` attr with value `"dropdown-element-kw"`, is present in the DOM [^1]. Then you click it, then you send `key-words` passed as arguments via the `send_keys` method.

Regarding the ssl certificate errors, *if checking for certificates is not relevant*, you could add to your `options` object the [arguments to ignore them](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/): `--ignore-certificate-errors` and `--ignore-ssl-errors`:

```
...

class Pracuj_PL_Extractor():
    def __init__(self, *, key_words = None, location = None, distance = None, specialty = NOT_SPECIFIED, tech = NOT_SPECIFIED, level = NOT_SPECIFIED, Working_Hours = NOT_SPECIFIED, operation_mode = NOT_SPECIFIED):        
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
...
```

Hope it helps, feel free to reply or add more informatin about the HTML your scrapping if you still can't work it out.

[^1]: Note that `presence_of_element_located()` *only checks if the element is **present** in the DOM*. You should check the HTML and see if that input field is present before it's visible or clickable, depending on the case you should use `visibility_of_element_located()` or `element_to_be_clickable()`

Comment: Thanks, for help, I changed the input_key_words, and now i use the `EC.visibility_of_element_located` method, it still does not work tho but I seem to find the element in question. Html can be found under [link](http://pracuj.pl), I am specifically looking for the biggest input box with "Stanowisko, firma słowa kluczowe" label(the site is only available in polish).
The selector I am using right now is `div[data-test="section-search-bar-parameters"] > div > div[data-test="dropdown-element-kw"] > div[data-test = "dropdown-trigger"] > div[data-test="input"] > input`.

Comment: I've looked in to it and the problem seems to be that when you click on the element that's a child of "dropdown-trigger", you're prompted to input data into another element, that's not visible before the click event, that *looks* identical but is distinct. I've found the correct selector to be:

`div[data-test="section-search-bar-parameters"] > div > div[data-test="dropdown-element-kw"] > div[data-test = "dropdown-content"] > div[class="core_mpoaefh"]> div[data-test="input"] > input`

Comment: Note that now you should click the first element, find the new visible element, click it, and *then* send the keys.

Comment: @s3r10us3r if you'd update your question to include the bits that are specific to the selector in question I'll update the answer to include this new info. As it stands the problems with the original code are solved by the answer.